# randomly iteration of function A Matlab scheme

Tags: matlab

could anyone help me with the following iteration scheme with Matlab code, where we start with a given $x\in \mathbb R$ and then with probability $p_1,p_2=1-p_2 $, we choose $g_1$ and $g_2$ and this way do the same for $10$ times, then I start choosing them with probability $q_1, q_2=1-q_1$ from the $11^{th}$ iteration say, where $p_1\ne p_2\ne q_1\ne q_2$.

I did like this but seems not to work the scenario I describe. Thanks for helping.

```
x0=something;
cumweight= [p_1; 1-p_1];
g1=x^2+1;
g2=3*x+x^2+1;
x = zeros(n,1);
y = zeros(n,1);

    n=20;
for i=1:10
    r = rand;
    choice = find(cumweight >r, 1 );
    switch (choice)
        case 1
            g1(i+1)=g1(x0);
        case 2 
            g2(i+1)=g2(x0);

    end
end
```

Comment: Your question is badly formatted and hard to understand. Pleas make it more clear. To mark text as code, use pairs of **`**, not **$**

Comment: @Eliahu Apparently the OP is trying to write LaTeX here; which is not supported on this site

Comment: I don't find LaTeX particularly easy to parse in a paragraph like this. Please [edit] your question and present it in a way that doesn't require LaTeX. Also, if I were to try to run your code I'd get an error "`something` undefined". Please make sure we can actually run your code, see [mre].

Comment: “This site should support LaTeX” but obviously it doesn’t. When you post a question, you can see that your LaTeX isn’t being formatted, why choose to post it like that anyway? Now you’ve posted your question as an image, which is not searchable and not accessible to all (e.g. screen readers will not not be able to read your question). Instead, write your question using normal language and code. If your question requires mathematics, apparently this site is not the right one to ask. (Hint: your question does not need any mathematical notation to be understandable.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that chooses g and theta independently of each other with probabilities 
 (i) [p, 1-p] for i <=10 and (ii) [q, 1-q] for 11 <= i <= 20

You can build upon it to perform the exact calculation for x(n+1) you require.

```
clc
clear all
close all
%x0=something;
p_1 = 0.2;
q_1 = 0.3;
g1=1;
g2=2;
theta1 = 1;
theta2 = 2;
n = 20;
x = zeros(n,1);
y = zeros(n,1);    
for i=1:20
    r1 = rand; % random number of choice of g1/g2
    r2 = rand; % random number of choice of theta1/theta2

    if(i <= 10)
         test = p_1;
    elseif(i <= 20) 
         test = q_1;
    end

    choiceG = test <= r1;
    choiceTheta = test <= r2;

    % chose theta
    if(choiceTheta)
        theta = theta1;
    else
        theta = theta2;
    end

    % chose G
    if(choiceG)
        % the text below is chosen with probability p_1 for i <=10 and
        % with probability q_1 for 11 <= i <= 20
        g = g1;
    else
        % the text below is chosen with probability (1 - p_1) for i <=10 and
        % with probability (1-q_1) for 11 <= i <= 20
        g = g2;
    end

    disp([' chose g' num2str(g) ' and theta' num2str(theta)]) % only for ilustration purpose
    % you can set the required computation for x_{n+1} here
end
```

Comment: Code right now just chooses between g1 and g2, you can enter a non-linear operation here and save it in a variable say out(i) = *some function*. You can then plot the the variable out. If you have more than 2 g's to choose from, one way is that instead of drawing a random number from a unifrom distribution, you can draw from a multinomial distribution (check wiki and matlab help). Instead of  'if-else', you can then use 'switch'. hint: test = find(mnrnd(1,[p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6])) will give you a value between 1-6 in test  where p1...p6 are probabilities of the 6 cases summing to 1.